# What is the Tor network exit node IP address turnover?

Tags: anonymity, exit-relays, web-proxy

I'm curious how frequently do the Tor network exit node IPs change?

More specifically, approximately what percentage in a given month still remain in use the next month?

Or do all typically stay in use and just new ones are added?

Comment: I can't give an answer. But I wonder, what exactly you'd like to know. Are the Exit-Relays stable in the Network? _or_ Do they (the Exit-Relays) stick to their IP-Address?